# Cannot reinstall Cassandra - "Node with address <IP> already exists" + "Could not find tokens for <IP> to replace"

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am trying to re-install Cassandra on a machine that had it previously installed. The service fails to start with a message of:

`A node with address /192.168.11.16 already exists, cancelling join. Use cassandra.replace_address if you want to replace this node.`

Following up by adding the following:

`JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.replace_address=192.168.11.16"`

to the end of my

`cassandra-env.sh`

and the service continues to fail to start with the following message:

`Could not find tokens for /192.168.11.16 to replace`

I have even tried starting it as 127.0.0.1 and localhost and using `nodetool removenode` and `nodetool assassinate 192.168.11.16` and nothing seems to be able to clear out whatever is making it persist. Any guidance on how to get it up and running properly on this machine again is greatly appreciated.

TIA
JH

Answer (score 1):

If your node already joined the cluster and not running then you should follow node replacement procedure as below.
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceNode.html

Comment: I went through this process without success. I monkeyed around with it for a few hours with no success. I finally decided to simply rebuild the node (thank you masterless architecture) and it's all up and running now.